# Plotly is not working module 'tenacity' has no attribute 'retry'

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I am trying to produce a simple scatter plot using Plotly

And all the time I am getting this error:

```
module 'tenacity' has no attribute 'retry'
```

I searched for solutions but nothing worked.

In particular, I have tried the following:

- Uninstall and install again plotly
- Upgrade pip and then upgrade plotly
- install tenacity into my environment

Can someone help?

Here is the python script I am using:

```
import plotly.express as px



 fig = px.scatter(df_performance, x="ytd", y="cagr", 
                     size ='Market Cap', template='plotly_dark',
                     color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis, title = 'S&P 500 Companies Perfomance the Last 4 months')
    fig.show()
```

where df_performance is just a pandas dataframe with three columns (ytd,cagr, Market Cap)

My python version is: 3.8.12

**Update: Here is the full trace**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/7g/gr9fl0cx43g5f42xf78n_str0000gn/T/ipykernel_28716/3796243394.py in <module>
      2                  size ='Market Cap', template='plotly_dark',
      3                  color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis, title = 'S&P 500 Companies Perfomance the Last 4 months')
----> 4 fig.show()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3396         import plotly.io as pio
   3397 
-> 3398         return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3399 
   3400     def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_plotly_utils/importers.py in __getattr__(import_name)
     34             rel_module = ".".join(rel_path_parts[:-1])
     35             class_name = import_name
---> 36             class_module = importlib.import_module(rel_module, parent_name)
     37             return getattr(class_module, class_name)
     38 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_renderers.py in <module>
     10 from plotly import optional_imports
     11 
---> 12 from plotly.io._base_renderers import (
     13     MimetypeRenderer,
     14     ExternalRenderer,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_base_renderers.py in <module>
     10 from plotly import utils, optional_imports
     11 from plotly.io import to_json, to_image, write_image, write_html
---> 12 from plotly.io._orca import ensure_server
     13 from plotly.io._utils import plotly_cdn_url
     14 from plotly.offline.offline import _get_jconfig, get_plotlyjs

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/Spyder_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py in <module>
   1453 
   1454 
-> 1455 @tenacity.retry(
   1456     wait=tenacity.wait_random(min=5, max=10), stop=tenacity.stop_after_delay(60000),
   1457 )

AttributeError: module 'tenacity' has no attribute 'retry'
```

Comment: do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Updated.

Answer (score 0):

- you have described the data so synthesized it
- used exactly your code, runs without issues.  **plotly** 5.5.0

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_performance = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ytd": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", freq="B", periods=100),
        "cagr": np.linspace(2, 5, 100) * np.random.uniform(.7,1,100),
        "Market Cap": np.linspace(5,20, 100) * np.random.uniform(.7,1,100),
    }
)

fig = px.scatter(
    df_performance,
    x="ytd",
    y="cagr",
    size="Market Cap",
    template="plotly_dark",
    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis,
    title="S&P 500 Companies Perfomance the Last 4 months",
)

fig
```

Comment: what python version you used?

Comment: Sadly, the issue for me persists even with your example. I have updated my question with the stacktrace

Comment: using python 3.9.7 but didn't see this with python 3.8 when I was using it.  seen this https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2907 but don't really see relationship to your issue